# Issue with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

[image][image]hi Iam new to iOS and i am trying to use CVCalender for custom calendar https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar#-cocoapods-
and i am try to install the cocoa pods but its getting error,
But i have muly cocopods in my file is these are use  full or i need to delete these things as shown in image[image]

[image]

can any one help me to how to install coacoa pods sucessfully and install cvcalender

after adding delegates also showing same error[image]

Comment: You are adding an extra $. That is the error. For installing cocoa pods go through this link https://cocoapods.org . Make sure you don't make typo mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Open terminal**

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**2.Setup the cocoapods master repo**

```
pod setup
```

download the master repo. The size is big approx 370.0MB

**3.Create xcode project and select root directory in terminal.**

```
cd "your XCode project root directory"
```

**4.Then type**

```
pod init
```

**5.Then open your project's podfile by typing in terminal**

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

**6.Add your project's dependencies in open text podfile.**

```
**for ex.** pod 'CVCalendar', '~> 1.5.2'
```

**7.Then install pods into your project by typing in terminal**

```
pod install
```

Now close your xcode project and open .xcworkspace xcode project file.
Happy Coding.

**Also refer cocoapods link.** https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: then what's your issue.

Comment: is there any issue with that or not if yes if i again install cocoapods it will add another file right?

Comment: above my answer 1 and 2 step in required one time. you reinstall cocoapods in xcode project just follow 3,4,5,6,7 step.

Comment: i have followed ur steps sucess fully but it showing using un resolved identifier when iam doing coding

Comment: [!] Automatically assigning platform ios with version 10.3 on target GMHospital because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform    how to resolve this eror

Comment: please check it i have added pod file

Comment: UPDATE BUT SAME PROBLE